# Find closest parentheses to string using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string  `{[ab]} {[c] } { [d] } {[f]} {    = [abc]  qwqw = =qwwq= =wq }`, I'm trying to extract a group by using a specific string which is inside one of the parentheses, e.g:

> ab -> {[ab]}
>
> d  -> { [d] }
>
> abc -> {    = [abc]  qwqw = =qwwq= =wq }

Once I get the result I want to replace it with something else.

I've attempted several different regex patterns:

```
\{(.*?\[(?:abc)\].*?)\}
([^}][{].*?\[(?:abc)\].*?[}])
({+?(?<=)\[(?:abc)\].*?[}])
^(?:.*)({.*?\[(?:abc)\].*?[}])
```

But none of them work properly. They either match too much of the string or too little of the string.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\{[^{}]*\[([abcd]+)\][^{}]*\}` See https://regex101.com/r/EpKpeZ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird it works! Do you mind posting it as an answer? I'd also like to see what would it look like if it only captures a single group that matches exactly the string inbetween say abc should only match abc not a,b, etc.

Comment: FYI, those are [braces](https://practicaltypography.com/parentheses-brackets-and-braces.html) (or curly brackets, or curly braces), not parentheses.

Comment: @Deadzone I have added it as an answer with another alternative .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `(?:abc)` will match a string `abc` and does not need the non capturing group. That will not match a single a or ab etc.

One option could be use a capturing group and a character class repeating 1 or more times any of the listed `[abcd]+` which might also be aaa if that is ok.

```
\{[^{}]*\[([abcd]+)\][^{}]*\}
```

In parts

- `\{` Match `{`
- `[^{}]*` Match 0+ times not `{` or `}`
- `\[` Match `[`
- `([abcd]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any of the listed
- `\]` Match `]`
- `[^{}]*` Match 0+ times not `{` or `}`
- `\}` Match `}`

---

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EpKpeZ/1/)

If you only want to match abc ab c or d you could also use an alternation matching ab with an optional c, or c or d

```
\{[^{}]*\[(abc?|c|d)\][^{}]*\}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LXGCx9/1)